# How to force asp.net MVC 2 to redirect to default controller/action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

In a brand new ASP.NET MVC2 project, I want the user to be redirected to

```
http://<mysite>/home/index
```

rather than

```
http://<mysite>/
```

We do this with our other sites for tracking purposes, to avoid the scenario where hits to the same default page show up as

```
http://<mysite>/
http://<mysite>/default.aspx
```

How do I accomplish this so that `http://<mysite>/` automatically redirects to whatever default controller/action I have set up in my routing? Please note that I am aware the two are functionally equivalent, as the default controller action will be executed either way. I'm just interested in forcing consistent URLs in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do it, no?

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string incomingUrl = HttpContext.Request.Url.LocalPath;

        if (incomingUrl == "/")
        {
            return Redirect("/home/index");
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```